# Automatic update for CursorAdapter is only for ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I've a listview with a cursoradapter. I've also a SQLite database.
Here is my question:
Is it possible that the auto-update works only with a ContentProvider and not with SQLite only?

Comment: What "auto-update" are you referring to?

Comment: Cursor is updated based on the data in the database, so my list is always update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cursors` are never updated, automatically or otherwise. They are not modified due to changes in wherever the `Cursor` came from.

*If* you are using the loader framework, with `CursorLoader`, *then* you will get a **fresh `Cursor`** delivered to you when data changes, *if*:

- You are querying a `ContentProvider`, and
- The `ContentProvider` is written to support `ContentObservers`

However:

- This is a different `Cursor` than before, requiring you to pass that to your `CursorAdapter`
- This does not work with other sources of `Cursors` (e.g., SQLite queries, `MatrixCursor`)
- This does not work if you query the `ContentProvider` by other means (e.g., `query()` on a `ContentResolver`)